# How can I create a new column in a dataframe on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to create a new column in my dataframe base on a condition and I keep getting a key error. I suspect it might have something to do with the indexing or headers but have hit a roadblock.

What I am trying to achieve is a new column which says gas or coal based on if the technology field (which has three possible inputs: CCGT, OCGT or Coal). So I wrote a formula which will return coal if the technology column has coal or gas if not but it didn't seem to work.

DF with desired column:

```
|                | settlementDate | 03/01/2022 | 04/01/2022 | 05/01/2022 | 06/01/2022 | 07/01/2022 | 08/01/2022 |          |
|----------------|---------------:|-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|----------|
| BM Unit ID   1 |     Technology |            |            |            |            |            |            | Gas/Coal |
|         CARR-2 |           CCGT |         24 |         25 |         27 |         29 |         21 |         12 | Gas      |
|         CDCL-1 |           CCGT |         13 |         22 |          8 |         25 |         12 |         16 | Gas      |
|        CNQPS-1 |           CCGT |         25 |        NaN |         33 |        NaN |        NaN |        NaN | Gas      |
|        CNQPS-2 |           CCGT |         20 |        NaN |         32 |        NaN |         32 |         26 | Gas      |
|        CNQPS-4 |           CCGT |         27 |        NaN |         41 |         33 |         35 |         31 | Gas      |
|         DAMC-1 |           CCGT |         23 |         21 |         38 |         34 |        NaN |        NaN | Gas      |
|         DIDCB6 |           CCGT |         28 |         11 |         11 |          8 |         19 |         15 | Gas      |
|         EECL-1 |           CCGT |          5 |         29 |          4 |          1 |          1 |          2 | Gas      |
|         FAWN-1 |           CCGT |          1 |          5 |          1 |          5 |          2 |          1 | Gas      |
|         FELL-1 |           CCGT |         34 |         39 |         47 |         43 |         41 |         34 | Gas      |
|         GRAI-6 |           CCGT |          4 |         18 |          2 |          4 |          3 |          3 | Gas      |
|         GRAI-7 |           CCGT |         10 |         27 |         15 |          9 |         15 |         11 | Gas      |
|         GRAI-8 |           CCGT |         11 |         28 |         36 |         16 |         26 |         25 | Gas      |
|         GRMO-1 |           CCGT |          2 |          7 |         10 |         24 |         11 |          6 | Gas      |
|         HUMR-1 |           CCGT |         22 |         30 |         37 |         37 |         33 |         28 | Gas      |
|         KEAD-2 |           CCGT |         30 |        NaN |        NaN |        NaN |        NaN |        NaN | Gas      |
|         LAGA-1 |           CCGT |         15 |         13 |         29 |         32 |         23 |         24 | Gas      |
|        PEMB-11 |           CCGT |         21 |          2 |          9 |         10 |          9 |         14 | Gas      |
|        PEMB-21 |           CCGT |          7 |          1 |          6 |         13 |          8 |          8 | Gas      |
|        PEMB-31 |           CCGT |         14 |          6 |         13 |          6 |          4 |          9 | Gas      |
|        PEMB-41 |           CCGT |          9 |          4 |          7 |          7 |         10 |         13 | Gas      |
|        PEMB-51 |           CCGT |          3 |          3 |          3 |         11 |         16 |        NaN | Gas      |
|         ROCK-1 |           CCGT |         31 |         34 |         42 |         38 |         38 |        NaN | Gas      |
|         SCCL-2 |           CCGT |         29 |        NaN |         16 |         28 |         25 |        NaN | Gas      |
|         SCCL-3 |           CCGT |         17 |         16 |         31 |          3 |         18 |         10 | Gas      |
|         SHBA-1 |           CCGT |         26 |         23 |         40 |         35 |         37 |        NaN | Gas      |
|         SHOS-1 |           CCGT |         16 |         15 |         28 |         15 |         29 |         27 | Gas      |
|         STAY-1 |           CCGT |         19 |         12 |          5 |         23 |          6 |          7 | Gas      |
|         STAY-2 |           CCGT |         18 |         20 |         18 |         21 |         24 |         20 | Gas      |
|         STAY-3 |           CCGT |          8 |         17 |         17 |         20 |         13 |         22 | Gas      |
|         STAY-4 |           CCGT |         12 |          8 |         20 |         18 |         14 |         23 | Gas      |
|        WBURB-1 |           CCGT |          6 |          9 |         22 |          2 |          7 |          5 | Gas      |
|       WBURB-41 |           COAL |         33 |         38 |         46 |         41 |         40 |         33 | coal     |
|       WBURB-43 |           COAL |         32 |         37 |         45 |         40 |         39 |         32 |          |
|         CARR-1 |           CCGT |        NaN |         33 |         26 |         27 |         22 |          4 |          |
|         DIDCB5 |           CCGT |        NaN |         10 |         35 |         22 |        NaN |        NaN |          |
|        FDUNT-1 |           OCGT |        NaN |         36 |         44 |        NaN |        NaN |        NaN |          |
|         GYAR-1 |           CCGT |        NaN |         26 |         14 |         17 |         20 |         21 |          |
|       KLYN-A-1 |           CCGT |        NaN |         24 |         12 |         19 |         27 |         29 |          |
|         LBAR-1 |           CCGT |        NaN |         19 |         25 |         31 |         28 |        NaN |          |
|         PETEM1 |           CCGT |        NaN |         35 |        NaN |        NaN |        NaN |        NaN |          |
|         SEAB-1 |           CCGT |        NaN |         32 |         34 |         36 |        NaN |         30 |          |
|         SEAB-2 |           CCGT |        NaN |         31 |         39 |         39 |         34 |        NaN |          |
|        WBURB-2 |           CCGT |        NaN |         14 |         21 |         12 |         31 |         18 |          |
|         COSO-1 |           CCGT |        NaN |        NaN |         30 |         42 |         36 |        NaN |          |
|         KEAD-1 |           CCGT |        NaN |        NaN |         43 |        NaN |        NaN |        NaN |          |
|         MRWD-1 |           CCGT |        NaN |        NaN |         19 |         26 |          5 |         19 |          |
|         SPLN-1 |           CCGT |        NaN |        NaN |         23 |         30 |         30 |        NaN |          |
|        WBURB-3 |           CCGT |        NaN |        NaN |         24 |         14 |         17 |         17 |          |
```

The code I have tried is:

```
rank_table_pivot['ave rank'] = rank_table_pivot.mean(axis=1)
rank_table_pivot['rank'] = rank_table_pivot['ave rank'].rank(method='dense', ascending=True)
rank_table_pivot.sort_values('ave rank')

    def coal_gas(Technology):
        if row['Technology'] == 'COAL':
            return "coal"
        else:
            return "gas"
        
    rank_table_pivot = rank_table_pivot['Technology'].apply(lambda Technology: map_Technology(Technology))
```

Comment: What is `map_Technology`?

Comment: I tried to map the 'Technology' column in the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `apply` like this:

```
def func(value):
    if value == "COAL":
        return "coal"
    else:
        return "gas"
        
rank_table_pivot["Gas/Coal"] = rank_table_pivot['Technology'].apply(func)
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't have that saved as I wrote over it but I have tried that first and got a similar key error on 'Technology'. Bit stumped why that would be the case so I was wondering maybe the way the headers are.